# How can I set the caption on an editor window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

I have implemented an annotate function in the Visual Studio Extension AnkhSVN2019 using a custom margin on an editor window.

In the current version, the tab on the editor window just contains the filename, and looks identical to a normal editor window. I would like to modify the caption, for example by appending the word "Annotated".

I am opening the editor window with

```
dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile
```

In the margin factory, I get the interface IWpfTextViewHost.

How can I modify the caption in the tab?

Comment: l think you can use `dte.ActiveWindow.Caption`. Please refer to [ActiveWindow Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.activewindow?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and when you open the editor window, you can use activewindow to catch it.

Comment: Unfortunately this lead to an **InvalidOperationException** with the message **"The caption of a Document or the MainWindow cannot be modified."**

Comment: Hi
The Caption can be set for tool windows in [Window.Caption Property][1]
Not sure how could you realize the custom margin the editor window. Could you please provide more specific detail in your project.
I am also try to customer the margin for an editor windows.

  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.window.caption?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: The custom margin is on an editor window, not a tool window. If you are looking for examples, the custom margin I implemented is in the [Annotate subdirectory of the Anhh.UI project](https://github.com/PhilJollans/AnkhSVN2019/tree/master/src/Ankh.UI/Annotate). I got some ideas from the [GitDiffMargin project](https://github.com/laurentkempe/GitDiffMargin). If you want to add a something to the glyph margin, there is a good walkthrough from Microsoft. You can add a simple margin in Visual Studio via Add/New Item -> C#/Extensibility/Editor -> Editor Margin.

Comment: Base on the getDiffMargin, It edit the caption by following code, It doesn't use the Object dte,itemoperations. I don't find the way to customize the editor window. 
using SVsDifferenceService = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsDifferenceService;
 
IVsDifferenceService differenceService = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsDifferenceService)) as IVsDifferenceService;
 
differenceService.OpenComparisonWindow2(leftFileMoniker, rightFileMoniker, caption, tooltip, leftLabel, rightLabel, inlineLabel, roles, (uint)grfDiffOptions);

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own `Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Shell.ViewElementFactory` from `<VS installation>\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ViewManager.dll` to overide the tab appearance i.e. showing the caption as you wish.

Look at [VSTabPath](https://github.com/DarkDaskin/VSTabPath) extension code for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to compile the VSTabPath extension and it certainly works, so I know there is a solution to the problem. I haven't quite figured out how it works yet, but I hope to understand it soon.